# Why would one not put CSS directly into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Situation:

I have a website that is served dynamically. In order to optimize the website's speed, all the CSS and javascript is put directly into the HTML document.

Pros:

- It cuts back on web requests
- Less files need to be downloaded
- Faster webpage download

Cons:

- Possible caching issue

So apart from the caching part, is there a reason *not* to do this?

Comment: It's completely impractical in my opinion. For a one page site maybe, but if your css rules are plentiful, it would just be very hard to manage.

Comment: Caching is pretty important if you really care about performance. If the CSS is very small, on the other hand, it probably doesn't matter much one way or the other.

Comment: It's less clean. But that's personal opinion.

Comment: Zero recycling. The HTML page is a bitch to administer. Also, don't know if I agree with "faster webpage download". There are caching issues, the fact that your HTML page will be heavily bloated to compensate for a lack of stylesheet - I would have said it would be a larger download,

Comment: From a technical perspective I think it is perfectly safe. From an organizational perspective it may become inconvenient after a while. Don't worry about web requests. That's just how the web works.

Comment: CSS is often reusable so you would potentially have a lot of duplicate code on your page.

Comment: If speed is your primary objective (as stated); the current trend is to add just enough in-page CSS to present the "above the fold" text (shooting for readability in < 1s). Other CSS should be minified and served async. If maintainability was more important you should use an external file nearly always.

Comment: @Malk that only makes sense if your CSS would only apply to half the page--which seems a bit odd (and impractical)

Comment: @DA https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

Comment: @Malk I don't always agree with Google, I guess. :)

Comment: I take it back, in a way. I guess I agree with them on their theory--it's just an incredibly impractical theory given that CSS is typically structured on a site-level or page-level in most cases. Even if you have custom CSS just for your 'above the fold' it's likely still using the larger site framework (like Bootstrap). It feels like a case of micro-optimization.

Comment: @DA. I hope your comments stay here, as I am making a graphic about css 'above the fold'. IT's very funny.

Comment: https://dribbble.com/shots/1905035-Above-The-Fold

Comment: @lharby I don't think I get it, but points for coming up with visual response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your CSS in a separate stylesheet file your site will be more maintainable, even if your CSS is inserted into the outgoing document by an automated server-side process.

By having your CSS in a separate file you make each page downloaded smaller.

However the benefits of "less files need to be downloaded" and "faster webpage download" are false. With a separate CSS file (*with an aggressive* `Expires:`*header*) your webpages will load faster compared to in-lining the CSS because the browser won't re-request the stylesheet on every subsequent page request (though the first visit would incur this cost, it really is minor).

Comment: So I essentially have a choice on whether to slightly slow down all the pages or slow down a single page more?

Comment: Any slowdown would be minute and imperceivable, this is an example of a micro-optimization that costs more in developer productivity and effort than it would make up for in end-value to your customer or visitor.

Comment: For SO it's adding 37kB (minimized css) to every html page (a question with a few answers is still less than 20kB) or one http request where the server can return a `304 not modified` header (and no content).

Comment: @Arjan with the `Expires` header the client wouldn't bother making the request that would result in a `304` response at all.

Answer (score 1):

`CSS` was designed for separating content from presentation. The W3Schools maintain that it is a good practice to use `html` for your structure, and `css` for styling.

This will make it easier for you. If you are working with large files, it's better to have a separate stylesheet for your css, or better yet, multiple stylesheets. It can be pretty unreadable to have inline styles or style tags in your html document.

Comment: I echo this as I think it is much more preferable to have light semantic markup and keep all the css separate.

Answer (score 0):

Set up both examples on a sub domain, and then test both at tools.pingdom.com

You'll see the differences between the two in how fast they load.

It's just tidier to keep files organised.

Comment: or check "Network" in google chrome

Answer (score 0):

Front end users usually won't notice performance increases like that, they will notice when your code has a bug and you are taking forever to fix it because the code is unreadable and hard to debug.

Nice readable code > optimized unreadable code

Comment: Well, they will notice when performance *decreases*. And they will care.

Comment: Not with the kind of stuff you are talking about. Its negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Quite many factors.

If your application is SPA and uses relatively compact CSS and self-contained scripts then it is better to serve it as single file indeed.

In all other cases you'd better use tools to compare various combinations.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a better question to ask.. why -wouldn't- you?  Unless you have a single page, you probably want to use the same styles on every page.  So, you don't want to have to write those over and over and over.

You're wasting time adding the CSS to the page (unless you are dynamically generating the CSS as well).  I'd think in most cases, you can just put in the link to the CSS in your generated page, and it'll end up in almost all cases (except for the initial page load for a new user) be faster on both the server and client end.

Unless you're generating the CSS at the same time, as well.